# configure SSL for Elasticbeanstalk single instance Passenger

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ssl, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried everything to enable SSL for my single instance on `Elasticbeanstalk` i have followed the link given on AWS for configuring it with `Passenger`. [AWS Link for Passenger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-ruby.html#Passenger) , I have deployed my ssl branch over `elasticbeanstalk` and Everything is updated also health of ENV is green but yet , i didnt find any change in Load Balancer.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you've mentioned single-instance in the question title, and load-balancer in the question body. which of the two environment types are you using?

Comment: can you tell me clearly that what you want i will update question. any help will be appreciated

Comment: is this env load balanced or single instance?

Comment: @Tal when i see configuration , then i the bottom i have load balancer in Network Tier. i really dont know much about it, i assumed it single due to one app running on it

Comment: if you see load-balancer than you're not in a single instance env, but rather a load balanced one. this is good as it simply means you've used the wrong documentation. i'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you've used the wrong documentation. as you're using a load balanced environment you need to follow the instructions here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

It's actually easier, as you let beanstalk load balancer full control over the HTTPS. The steps are:
1. upload your key via `aws iam upload-server-certificate`
2. go to the beanstalk web console and in the load-balancer section pick that uploaded key
3. that's it - you are now set with HTTPS
(all of this is detailed in the documentation mentioned above)

Comment: upload-server-certificate? with which extension certificate will be?

Comment: there are some files.
.crt, .pem , when i download my certificate from where i bought it.

Comment: 1. upload your key via aws iam upload-server-certificate.
which key ? thats what i am asking?

Comment: seems like you're stuck uploading the key. Here's an example of how I upload my thawte certificate: `aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name my-certificate-thawte-151222 --certificate-body file:///tmp/thawte.www.mysite.co.crt.pem --private-key file:///tmp/thawte.www.mysite.co.key.pem --certificate-chain file:///tmp/thawte.ca.crt.chain`
note that all files are pem formatted

Comment: Actually am using `digicert` for certificate and its giving me different files,
3 files = DigiCertCA.crt,TrustedRooot.crt,evercam_io.crt
i can have all these three in .pem format as well, now issues is how to get private key public key from this?

Comment: these files are not your key. you need to create one (https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/openssl.htm)

Comment: can i have you on this? http://serverfault.com/questions/748462/ssl-certificate-complication-for-aws-eb